# How to get a receiving address from Bitcoin Wallet app?

Tags: address

So, I'm trying to obtain my winnings from this online casino OZWIN CASINO, which is based out of Australia, and I'm located in the United States. Problem is that I've never used Bitcoin and I've just created an account using Bitcoin Wallet app. The casino is asking for my Bitcoin address so that they can send me my payment. Where do I obtain this address?

Answer (score 1):

> Where do I obtain this address?

In the ["Bitcoin Wallet" Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet&hl=en&gl=US) <sup>1</sup> you get a new address by clicking "Request Coins" at the bottom left of the main page in the app.

[image: Request Bitcoins page in app]

The address is in that 2D barcode - specifically a QR-code. The above is an example, don't use it! You can copy the address to the clipboard using the copy icon at the top. You can then paste it into a message or use it some other way.

You can also get a list of addresses (with one marked as current address for receiving) by clicking the "Address book" icon at the top that looks like a label tag

[image: icon for address book]

---

1. This wallet is sometimes known as the Schildbach wallet because the official name is so generic and useless as a search term. There are many different Bitcoin wallets and many different Bitcoin wallet developers.